# How to get a 1 week-fast track British passport replacement appointment upgraded to the 1-day premium service

Tags: uk, london, passports, uk-citizens

Complete nightmare so far, missed flight and missing foreign visa as well.

Going to [IPS](http://www.homeoffice.gov.uk/agencies-public-bodies/ips/) tomorrow with a fast-track appointment in hand and aiming to upgrade to the premium one-day service. Anyone had any luck with that approach before - or tips?

EDIT: Thank you. It's for a British passport, the visa is a separate issue I'm working on. Though any tips or tricks on how to get a 1 week-fast track passport replacement appointment upgraded to the 1-day premium service would be helpful.

Comment: I don't really understand what the question here is.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee not sure either, I guess he's trying to find a way to get a new passport as fast as humanly possible?

Comment: @nc - welcome to Travel.SE.  Your question is rather vague - it's a little hard to tell what you're after.  I suggest you read the [faq] as it has a handy guide on how to ask questions on here.  For a start, your title should usually be the question.  We have many travellers on here from the UK and plenty with experience with getting new passports, so if you could elaborate with the actual problem you're having, people will be happy to help :)

Comment: There's no chance of the IPS giving you a visa for another country! You'll have to re-apply for that. Get a police report for your lost passport.

Comment: Which visa are you after? Sometimes you can get around it...

Comment: It's for a British passport to be replaced. I have an appointment this afternoon for the 1 week fast track service but hope to upgrade it to a same day premium one based on just having missed my flight.

Comment: @MarkMayo updated with more info

Comment: (How can anyone "not understand" this question?  It could not be more straightforward and clearly-written. Upgrade "fasttrack" service to the "premium" service.   Anyway some recent news on this ... https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/123205/the-uks-instant-passport-service-how-long-currently-to-appointment  )

Answer (score 9):

So I've figured it out. If you lose a British passport in the UK and require a new one ASAP get the first appointment at IPS that you can and then request the same-day service in person.

If the passport you lost is a biometric one (issued in 2008 onwards) they will be able to do it -- if it's not, then you'll have to wait for a week. Your travel, or other circumstances don't seem to matter.