# What counts as “about to expire” for UK paper premium passport renewal?

Tags: uk, passports

I’m a British citizen living abroad (I don’t believe this belongs on the expatriates stack exchange because my specific question could apply equally to British citizens in the UK - indeed it’s about a service only available within the UK), and wish to renew my passport.

In a few weeks I’ll be making (for unrelated reasons) a short trip to Liverpool, which happens to be one of the cities where the [paper premium passport renewal service](https://www.gov.uk/get-a-passport-urgently/paper-premium-service) is available. The page says it can be used to:

> renew a red adult passport that has expired or is about to expire

(Or when changing name, but that’s not relevant to me).

There doesn’t appear to be any definition of when a passport is considered “about to expire”.

At the time of my trip, my passport will have approximately 7 months remaining before it expires. Is this remaining validity period short enough to qualify as “about to expire”?

Comment: It's 100% OK, but you will NOT at all get the "extra time".  Gone are the days. One point. I would recommend the ("even more amazing") "online premium service". It is only a little more expensive. (ie, instead of getting ripped-off senseless for the Right To Exist, it's just a tad more than ripped-off-senseless.) As you know the new face of statism in the UK is hyper-efficient, smiling statism. The "instant online" service is amazing. (1) sit down at PC, type a few things in; upload a pic. (2) Go to a fairly specific appointment time, wait 10-15 mins tops, and get new passport in hand. Whoa.

Comment: Some info here in the Qs and As  https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/123205/the-uks-instant-passport-service-how-long-currently-to-appointment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not get the extra time left on your passport anymore, but 7 months is well within the normal 'need to replace due to near to expire' for a passport.

It used to be that you would get up to 9 months extra on your new passport if you renewed it before it was expired.
I have heard that they changed the extra time added due to other countries not accepting the extra time, only allowing your passport to be used till 10 years after its starting date, but I am not sure about the reason.

I do know someone from the UK who lives abroad and comes to England (in his case mostly London) to renew his passport, as he can not send it in. (Need to cross borders on almost a daily basis.)

Comment: For example, EU rules for non-EU passport (which will be relevant soon) is: Passport must not be older than 10 years, and passport must be valid for another 6 months, while for EU citizens the passport needs just to be valid. So I think the extra time would still be useful because it allows you to use the passport for 10 years, not 9 years six months.

Comment: Your friend should get a second passport, which is perfectly legal and possible if you have a good reason for it, so that he can keep travelling on one while the other is being renewed.